# Selenium access a form field with bad id

Tags: selenium, robotframework

Looking for the best approach to enter / read a value from a form field that lacks human readable ids / references.

The basic outline looks like

```html
<div id="form-2143">
  <div id="numberfield-1234">
    <label id="numberfield-1234-label">
      <span class="x-form-label">Field Name 1</span>
    </label>
    <div id="numberfield-1234-body">
      <div id="numberfield-1234-wrap">
        <input id="numberfield-1234-input" class="form-field" componentid="numberfield-1234">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

There are more class defs and attributes involved, but above is the "basics" I have to work with.

This form has a number of entries, and there are more forms like it, so I am looking for a way to search for the label name, and access the input field within the same container.

I lack control of the site and cannot edit the HTML structure of the site; meaning I cannot give sensible names to the ids, but want to avoid hard referencing the poor names. Any suggestions on how to get Robot Framework & selenium to reference these elements?

Comment: Check `XPath`: `//label[span[text()="Field Name 1"]]/following-sibling::div//input`

Comment: You should also look for typos. You have "lable" instead of "label".

Comment: Cheers guys, @Andersson that works grand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlighting Andersson's answer in the comments

Using the XPath

```
//label[span[text()="Field Name 1"]]/following-sibling::div//input
```

Works for the above example.

The key part that answers the question of how to reference nearby elements is

```
 /following-sibling
```